# Return a generic type <String,Double>

Tags: java, generics

I have this string:

```
String str = "Hey;2.3232";
```

and want to return this pair:

```
<Hey,2.3232>
```

Being the pair type "String,Double", how can I do this in Java?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public static Pair<String, Double> parseItem(String str) {
    String[] array = str.split(";");

    String s = array[0];
    Double s1 = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);

    //and then i don't know how to return it

}
```

Comment: depends on the implementation of Pair but I would assume something like  `return new Pair(s, s1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the Pair class has a constructor that accepts the two parameters :

```
return new Pair<String,Double>(s,s1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Pair<String, Double> parseItem(String str) {
    String[] array = str.split(";");

    String s = array[0];
    Double s1 = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
    return Pair.create(s, s1) ; // Or some form of Pair constructor
}
```